# Cypress 7+ hanging in IC

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cypress, webpack-dev-server, cypress-component-test-runner

After migrating to latest Cypress versions (7.0.1, 7.2.0, 7.3.0) using `webpack-dev-server`, I'm experiencing the same issue when running my React component tests in IC (Jenkins) using a Cypress `cypress/browsers:node14.16.0-chrome89-ff86` docker image while everything is working fine locally (Windows 10). The job hangs on :

`ℹ ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /__cypress/src/index.html`

before stopping after 15 min due to timeout.

This is the script launching the tests:

```
cypress run-ct --browser chrome --headless --config screenshotsFolder=/reports/cypress/screenshots
```

This is my `cypress/plugins/index.js`:

```
const { startDevServer } = require('@cypress/webpack-dev-server')
const injectReactScriptsDevServer = require('@cypress/react/plugins/react-scripts')
const webpackConfig = require('../webpack.config.js')

module.exports = (on, config) => {
  // `on` is used to hook into various events Cypress emits
  // `config` is the resolved Cypress config

  if (config.testingType === 'component') {
    injectReactScriptsDevServer(on, config)
    on('dev-server:start', async (options) => startDevServer({options, webpackConfig}))
  }

  return config
}
```

This is my `cypress/webpack.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx", ".d.ts", ".json"]
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'ts-loader',
                options: {
                    compilerOptions: {
                        "noEmit": false
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['@babel/preset-env','@babel/react']
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

These are the dependencies I use:

```
"cypress": "7.3.0",
"@cypress/react": "5.7.0",
"@cypress/webpack-dev-server": "1.3.0",
"ts-loader": "8.2.0",
```

Any ideas ?

Thanks for you help

Comment: Do you have any globally installed packages that could be the reason for the difference?

Answer (score 0):

The below worked for me

cypress run-ct --browser chrome --headless --config screenshotsFolder=/reports/cypress/screenshots -- --spec

The two extra dashes are needed before --spec to target a file or folder